# Incorrect Count of IP Visits

Tags: sql, count

This Query ...

```
SELECT a.*
FROM LicenseHistory a
JOIN (
    SELECT LicenseID, date as date, COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) as IPcount
    FROM LicenseHistory 
    WHERE (LicenseID= 24965)
    GROUP BY LicenseID,IPAddress,Date
    /*HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT IPAddress) > 1*/
) b ON (a.LicenseID = b.LicenseID) AND date(a.date) = date(b.date)
order by date desc, LicenseID desc
```

returns ...

```
Date                lic     users   IP Address    country   Count
2013-05-14 13:44:56 24965   15  70.60.96.98 US  1455
2013-05-14 13:44:56 24965   15  70.60.96.98 US  1455
2013-05-14 11:50:34 24965   15  72.252.247.148  JM  111
2013-05-14 11:50:34 24965   15  72.252.247.148  JM  111
2013-03-29 07:40:37 24965   15  184.39.241.223  US  14
```

The count column is clearly incorrect since a query to extract just the distinct IP's returns a count of 123 (for 70.60.96.98). How does this query arrive at a count of 1455? I want to count how many times license 24965 arrived from 70.60.96.98 on 2013-05-14 and similar for each ip in the list on each date.

Answer (score 2):

Why such a hideously complicated query when

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM LicenseHistory
WHERE (LicenseID = 24965) AND (IPAddress = '70.60.96.98')
```

would do the trick?

Comment: Because your query does not tell me how many times IP #x  with License #y visited on Date #z. In fact your query doesn't account for the dates at all. To be fair, the question did seem to be cut off so I will edit it above, it was ...  I want to count how many times license 24965 arrived from 70.60.96.98 on a particular date.